# Why are typescript namespaces outdated?

Tags: typescript

Namespaces in typescript are outdated according to the eslint rule [no-namespace](https://github.com/typescript-eslint/typescript-eslint/blob/master/packages/eslint-plugin/docs/rules/no-namespace.md). Why is that? And what are the downsides and upsides of using namespaces and ES2017 modules respectively?

Comment: Relevant reading: https://michelenasti.com/2019/01/23/is-typescript-namespace-feature-deprecated.html

Answer (score 0):

## NameSpaces (compared to ES Modules)

+ve: ES Modules are one per file. Namespaces can be multiple per file.

-ve: Its not supported in JavaScript and has to be transpiled away by TypeScript